# HTML form submit button with custom image has background image with joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

I am using Joomla

My Form button with a image has a background image behind it - where is it coming from?

Is this a default for a form submit button? Is it something Joomla does?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrqLZ.png

```
    .wrap
{
text-align:center;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
div.signupButton input {
    background:url(../../images/signup.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 303px;
    height: 72px;
    border: none;
}

div.signinButton input {
    background:url(../../images/login.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 303px;
    height: 72px;
    border: none;
}
```

the html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="php_scripts/css/homesign.css" type="text/css">
<form action="http://.." method="post">
<div class="signupButton"><INPUT type="submit" name="" value=""></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post a link to your website?

Comment: I don't really understand your requirement, but let try this:
`div.signupButton input {
background: url(../../images/signup.png) no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
width: 303px;
height: 72px;
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}`

Comment: that did it - guess its a box shadow? Place as answer if you would like and Ill mark as correct - Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.signupButton input { 
background: url(../../images/signup.png) no-repeat; 
cursor: pointer; 
width: 303px; 
height: 72px; 
border: none; 
border-radius: 0; 
-webkit-box-shadow: none; 
box-shadow: none; 
}
```

Comment: this does provide an answer - it was a shadowbox and Minh Nguyen solved this perfectly!